# How to use JS in Framework7?

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

I create an application with [framework7](http://framework7.io/). Now I try to execute a `javascript` in my `page-content`, but it doesn't execute.

```
<div class="pages">
<div class="page  close-panel" data-page="item">
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="content-block-title">Title</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          alert("testoutput"); // no alert
          console.log("TEST"); // no log
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I run this javascript code ?

**UPDATE**

The page is loaded from an other HTML-Page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Callbacks (onPageInit) to execute code

Answer (score 5):

I had never heard of Framework7 before this, but after taking a look at the docs, I don't believe you are going to be able to use Javascript this way.

It would appear that for JS events, you have to scope the event inside a Framework7 constructor:

```
var myApp = new Framework7();

var $$ = Dom7;

$$('.alert-text').on('click', function () {
    myApp.alert('Here goes alert text');
});
```

Of course the above example is taken directly from the F7 documentation, and is dependent on a click event, but you may be able to try out the alert event as a method of `myApp` and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myApp = new Framework7();

//Add callback function that will be executed when Page with data-page="about" attribute will be initialized
myApp.onPageInit('dashboard', function (page) {
    console.log('dashboard page initialized');
    console.log(page);
});

// Option 2. Using live 'page:init' event handlers for each page (not recommended)
$$(document).on('page:init', '.page[data-page="dashboard"]', function (e) {
    console.log('dashboard loaded with page:init');
    createGraph();
});
```

Above worked me well.. although following didnt work.

```
myApp.onPageInit('dashboard', function (page) {
    console.log('dashboard page initialized');
    console.log(page);
});
```

Comment: In my case, where do you define the page methods, for example, i dont like the fact that i have to put all the different page scripts and methods under app.js it gets big file and confusing. Should i divide the logic into diferent ".js" files?

Answer (score -1):

If you written any javascript code inside index.html file, Put that code in

```
    <head> 
      <script>
         alert("testoutput"); // no alert
         console.log("TEST"); // no log
      </script>
    </head> like this, which is defined in index.html file 

Or ,if you want write JS code for some particular html file ,

Do like this

 <div class="page  close-panel" data-page="item">
 <div class="page-content">
    <div class="content-block-title">Title</div>
</div>
    <script>
      alert("testoutput"); // no alert
      console.log("TEST"); // no log
    </script>
 </div>
```